# Permanently resolve Unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, filesystemwatcher

To resolve this issue I got there to the link provided by vscode

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc

Ok, this, corrects the error, But **when I restart the Linux and again open my React project,**
I get the Same error. 
`max_user_watches` file again gets the value of `8192` as no. of max files.

My react server is not starting due to this issue.

Then I again follow the same step of the link provided, this sometimes gets frustrating.

Any permanent Help I could get from you.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

Just disable this built-in extension: **TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features**

[image: TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features]